# Lazily evaluated switchIfEmpty for Project Reactor's Mono

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm looking for a way to retrieve an alternative Mono in case the original one is empty. The closest one I found is `Mono.switchIfEmpty`, but my problem with it is that I can't pass a lambda expression to it so it's being called even when the Mono has a non-empty value. This is sort of like `Optional.orElse` vs `Optional.orElseGet`.

Here is a sample:

```
return someService.findSomeElements()           // returns a Flux<Element>
                  .filter(this::checkIfMatches)
                  .singleOrEmpty()
                  .switchIfEmpty(...);          // <-- I want to use lambda here
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrap the alternative `Mono` in a `Mono.defer` inside the `switchIfEmpty` and it will be lazily instantiated only when the original is empty.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working, but I wonder why isn't there a simpler solution i.e. having an overloaded version like `switchIfEmpty(Supplier alternate)`...?

Comment: In Reactor 3.2 they have a Kotlin extension
fun <T> Mono<T>.switchIfEmpty(s: () -> Mono<T>): Mono<T> = this.switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer { s() })